# Numpy: Adding elements to array print

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to add elements to array print output. What I have done is like that(from 'Fallen Apart' my last post):

```
c = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
for i, row in enumerate(c):
    print('G' + str(i+1) + ': ' + str(row))
```

Result:

```
G1: [0 1 2]
G2: [3 4 5]
G3: [6 7 8]
```

What I want to do is to print like this:

```
G1: [1:0 2:1 3:2]
G2: [1:3 2:4 3:5]
G3: [1:6 2:7 3:8]
```

Anyone can help me with it? THanks!

Comment: what do you want to add? I can't make sense of `[1:0 2:1 3:2]`, could you please clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: Just add `1:, 2: ,3:... ` in sequence before each value of each row in this array.

Comment: `[1:0 2:1 3:2]` is what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to your code:

```
c = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
col_id = np.arange(c.shape[1])+1
for i, row in enumerate(c):
    print('G'+str(i+1)+': '+'[%s]'%' '.join([str(a)+':'+str(b) for a,b in zip(col_id,row)]))
```

or another equal solution:

```
c = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
col_id = np.arange(c.shape[1])+1
for i, row in enumerate(c):
    print('G'+str(i+1)+': '+'[%s]'%' '.join(["{}:{}".format(a,b) for a,b in zip(col_id,row)]))
```

output:

```
G1: [1:0 2:1 3:2]
G2: [1:3 2:4 3:5]
G3: [1:6 2:7 3:8]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help,sir! I try to adapt your code to mine.But it does not work to an array of 10*24,it will only output from `1:...to 10:`, other values  are ignored.How to solve this kind of problem?Many thanks!

Comment: I try to adapt it to mine（10*24）.The output is like that ` G1 : [1:xx,2:xx,..10:xx (from 11 to 24 missed)] `